# APM won't show version

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

When I run the following in cmd.exe(also in ps with and without admin privileges);
    `apm -v`

I get the following error;

```
internal/child_process.js:274
   var err = this._handle.spawn(options);
                     ^

TypeError: Bad argument
    at TypeError (native)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:274:26)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.12.6\resources\app\apm\lib\apm-cli.js:149:17)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

What gives?

Comment: Sounds like you may want to file an issue on their github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because you haven't passed the actual parameter in accordance to the formal parameter.Go check your line 274 in `child_process.js` file. There you shall find that `spawn` function is being given invalid argument.

Developing in `node.js` huh ? include the tag please !